# Share Folder With Kali Linux & Windows 7

Tags: kali-linux

I Have Kali Linux Host And Windows 7 Guest In Virtual Box. So How I can share File I tried but can't fix, So show me the way for share file from Virtual Box windows 7 to Kali Linux

Comment: Hello Coder Hamza. It's looking likely that you're about to get another "Why won't anyone help me" closure. Please could I strongly suggest that while you start to learn about Linux-based systems you choose a more friendly distribution. Kali is not a beginner's distribution. This will also improve your chances of getting help here - we expect Kali users to be competent Linux users and beginners' questions tend to be shut down fast.

Comment: I would also advise taking our tour. Asking vague/too broad questions, and/or asking for tutorials is off-topic per our FAQ no matter whether Kali or other distribution.

Comment: @roaima:  Well, the question says “I have Kali Linux host …”.  Sure, the OP may be totally confused, and using terminology incorrectly, but we have to take him at his word.  But I agree: that edit was no improvement.

Comment: @RalfFriedl: I don’t know if you will get notified about this comment, but I’ll put it here anyway. Barely 80% of suggested edits are good. (I personally believe that the number is closer to 60%, but others may disagree.) You have an approve rate of 98%. Please be more careful about that “Approve” button.

Comment: @G-Man I missed that while reviewing and then couldn't retract my edit rejection text.

Answer (score 1):

Reading your question; if you want to transfer files from linux Server to Windows VM in same device, you can use from `LINUX SCP/SFTP/FTP` to transfer, and for Windows install `WinSCP` to receive them.

I guess I am gonna help you to modify the question, for more answers related you want to got.

[FTP Protocol (Basic commands)](https://www.serv-u.com/features/file-transfer-protocol-server-linux/commands)

[WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php)